# Copy table row by row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, cursor

I'm doing some trigger performance optimizations and i want to test it. I have a actual trigger and a modified trigger and i want on real data run a test on the old trigger and the new trigger and compare it. I want to copy table A to A_BCK row by row. Table A has about 60 columns and 4000 rows, so my trigger will be 4000 times executed and i can use it for performance test.

I've read about cursors, but cant figure out how use a cursor and variable for row by row copying (not select into a_bck or insert into a_bck select from a which both generate just one insert).

My row copying procedure as for now looks like this:

```
declare @actualrow varchar(15);

DECLARE eoauz CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT * FROM A

open eoauz
fetch next from eoauz into @actualrow
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
 /* INSERT INTO A_BCK VALUES FROM @actualrow  */
fetch next from eoauz into @actualrow
end
close eoauz
deallocate eoauz
```

Of course this does not work. I need something like a row variable instead varchar. Can someone help how to accomplish my task?

Comment: Why are doing this row by row? MSSQL is set based. Avoid using cursors, especially in triggers - unless you like living in a world of pain.

Comment: I dont do this _in_ my trigger. I want to do this to _test_ my trigger. I need a way to execute my trigger on real data.

Comment: Hmm, if you delete the ` into @actualrow` bit it returns the whole row back to the client. I'm not sure if there is syntax to insert that row into another table somehow.

Comment: @Martin - No, not into a table variable: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/e6fef818-0001-4803-9653-f65a2e66a34c/

Comment: @cyberkiwi - My answer should work with a TV.

Comment: @Martin - never thought of passing it through EXEC. Good one

Answer (score 4):

I don't often work with cursors so there may be a more straightforward way I'm missing...

```
SELECT TOP 0 *
INTO   #t
FROM   master..spt_values /*Create an empty table of correct schema*/

DECLARE eoauz CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   master..spt_values

OPEN eoauz

INSERT INTO #t
EXEC ('fetch next from eoauz')

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  INSERT INTO #t
  EXEC ('fetch next from eoauz')

CLOSE eoauz

DEALLOCATE eoauz

SELECT *
FROM   #t

DROP TABLE #t
```

Comment: What a pity. I've messed up with voting and cannot upvote this answer anymore. What I did is I upvoted it and then quickly called my vote back to check first if the method works. And it has. Now I'm trying to upvote it again, but it keeps saying my vote is now locked until the answer is edited. Is it really so stubborn? Your answer doesn't seem to need any substantial modification unless you would like to add an almost meaningless `select * from #t` at the end (your example is merely a test anyway). Otherwise, it's my thought exactly. So, a due upvote is pending.

Comment: @Andriy - Thanks! I've made the suggested change.

Comment: And there goes +1. (*aside*) I wonder if that vote block thing in may case is an issue or a feature...

Answer (score 2):

Sample table for code below

```
create table A(ID INT IDENTITY, a int, b int)
create table B(ID INT, a int, b int)
insert A select 1,2 union all select 3,4 union all select 5,6
```

You need a variable for each column. See example below

```
declare @id int, @a int, @b int
DECLARE eoauz CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT * FROM A
open eoauz
fetch next from eoauz into @id, @a, @b
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
 INSERT B VALUES( @id, @a, @b )
fetch next from eoauz into @id, @a, @b
end
close eoauz
deallocate eoauz
```

I prefer not to use cursors and instead use WHILE loops whenever possible

```
declare @id int
select top 1 @id = id from A order by ID
while @@ROWCOUNT > 0 begin
    insert B select * from A where ID=@id  -- one row
    select top 1 @id = id from A where id > @id order by ID
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What i dont like is that i have 60 columns and so i have to declare 60 variables. Furthermore i want the cursor only to use for testing. I dont have any cursors in the production DB. So really guys have no fear that i will use it in production ;-)

Comment: @Robert - see while loop alternative (which can also work on the cursor) using one column (key) to go back to table

Answer (score 0):

I would select your table's primary key into your cursor variable.  This uniquely identifies a single row, which you can then easily select:

```
declare @pk varchar(15);

DECLARE eoauz CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT PK FROM A

open eoauz
fetch next from eoauz into pk
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
INSERT INTO A_BCK select * from A where PK = @pk
fetch next from eoauz into pk
end
close eoauz
deallocate eoauz
```

I think this method has a big advantage in being easy to understand and read.